# Alertmanager docker. Set telegram_configs bot_token and chat_id from environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have alertmanager/config.yml

```
   receivers:
      - name: 'telegram'
        telegram_configs:
          - send_resolved: true
            api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
            bot_token: '123456:ASDFGH-:LKHHGFGD-WERWERWER'
            chat_id: 12345
            parse_mode: 'Markdown'
```

I whant

docker-compose.yml:

```
alertmanager:
        image: prom/alertmanager
        ports:
            - 9093:9093
        environment:
            - TELEGRAM_ADMIN=12345
            - TELEGRAM_TOKEN='123456:ASDFGH-:LKHHGFGD-WERWERWER'
```

alertmanager/config.yml

```
   receivers:
      - name: 'telegram'
        telegram_configs:
          - send_resolved: true
            api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
            bot_token: ${TELEGRAM_TOKEN}
            chat_id: ${TELEGRAM_ADMIN}
            parse_mode: 'Markdown'
```

But this option does not work (

Where is the error?

Comment: Alertmanager doesn't support any templating engine that populates values from environment variables. You're supposed to populate those yourselves using configuration management, for example.